# Adding a USB eject button to the panel/dock

Tags: mount, panel, usb-drive, docky

I wish to have a unmounter for my USB Drives. I use docky, and tied the in-built helper, but it displays the internal drives too. But I dont want all the drives, only those on USB.

Can't I have such an "ejecter" in the notification area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [USB Safe Removal application indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/safely-remove-usb-drives-using-a-nifty-application-indicator-updated-with-new-icon/).

[image: indicator usb screenshot]

Comment: do you know where the setting for that app are? I changed something, and now the indicator doesnt show up. I tried re-installing , but its still not working.

Comment: nvm, i found it. It was in ~/.config/indicator-usb

Answer (score 1):

There is a "drivemount" panel applet, but it shows all disks that aren't listed in `/etc/fstab`, so not only USB drives.  So IIRC you can avoid internal drives to be shown by adding them to fstab (even if not auto-mounted).  I assume the same might be true for Docky.